# How does one test a gem with native extensions when bundler includes gem from source?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I hope I'm being a bit dense, but I can't figure out how one is supposed to develop and test gems with native extensions using bundler when bundler seems not to build them.

I have a gem, `swig_try1` which is just my exercise in how to build a native extension. I can build the gem and install it and I see the expected `Building native extensions` message, the build succeeds, and when I go to another directory, I can require the gem and use methods defined in the native extension.

My problem lies in the fact that when I run `bundle install` I see this line:

```
Using swig_try1 (0.0.1) from source at .
```

But I don't see the `Building native extensions` message, and it doesn't show up in my directory structure:

```
.
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
├── Rakefile
├── ext
│   └── swig_try1
│       ├── extconf.rb
│       └── swig.c
├── lib
│   ├── swig_try1
│   │   └── version.rb
│   └── swig_try1.rb
├── pkg
│   └── swig_try1-0.0.1.gem
└── swig_try1.gemspec
```

i.e, no `Makefile` was generated in `ext/swig_try1`, as well as no `swig_try1.bundle` (in my rvm gems directory, I see these files).

I could go about my business and only ever use my gem from some other directory...but what about tests? I'm used to using rspec from my gem directory, but from there it always tries to load the version at `.` which doesn't have the native extension built.

This [issue on github](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1679) suggests that bundler might not be able to handle this? How can that be possible?

Please help me see what I'm missing.

Comment: I noticed my answer covers testing, but does not cover local reference in a project `Gemfile`. The answer to that depends on how you choose to deploy your project - the chances are you will need to drop the local link if and when you start to share your project that uses your gem-in-development. How you choose to do that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally this is done as a `rake` task e.g. `rake compile`, which you ensure is run before tests.

I put together a skeleton gem that does this, amongst other standard things expected in a native-extension gem, here: https://github.com/neilslater/ruby_nex_c

The key lines in the `Rakefile` are:

```
require 'rake/extensiontask'

gemspec = Gem::Specification.load('foo.gemspec')
Rake::ExtensionTask.new do |ext|
  ext.name = 'foo'
  ext.ext_dir = 'ext/foo'
  ext.lib_dir = 'lib/foo'
  ext.gem_spec = gemspec
end

task :default => [:compile, :test]
```

You then can run the combined compile/test with the simple command `rake`, which is quite handy for Travis CI.

Many other structures are possible - I gleaned this one by reading through a variety of gems on github, until I found something that I felt was a good fit to a gem created with `bundle gem`.

Comment: Great! Exactly the nice simple solution I was looking for.